# Can we assign more than one variable in on SELECT Statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Can we assign  more than one variable in on SELECT Statement ?

Like:

```
SELECT @variable1 = c1+c2  , @variable2 = c1-c2  from someView
```

it dosn't work in SQL Server

please help

Thanks...

Comment: it's absolutely legal syntax if your select returns single row. what kind of error message do you accept?

Comment: it keeps telling me " Error syntax near ","

Comment: @Khaleel Hmoz: it this the *exact* code you are running?

Comment: This is absolutely perfect code - either you didn't post your real SQL statement, or you aren't telling us something else that causes this to fail..... is there a problem in the view, maybe?? Also, can you post the **exact** error message??

Comment: no im doing like SELECT x1 = (select sum(c1+c2) ) , x2 =(Select sum(c2-c3) )  FROM  Table when Somecondtion    aww i found whats the problem  im  just trying to do two selection in the same level and have share the same condtion  to make one hit on that table not two

Comment: yes thx @gbn and  @marc_s  its my fault  it should work but the problem in my code i just found out that

Comment: @Khaleel Hmoz: so, you **have not** posted real code? Voting to close.

Comment: You need to have a `.... FROM SomeTable` in your inner SELECT statements!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server allows this

```
CREATE TABLE fish (c1 int, c2 int)
INSERT fish VALUES (1, 2)
GO
DECLARE @v1 int, @v2 int
SELECT
   @v1 = c1-c2, @v2 = c1+c2
FROM
  fish

SELECT @v1, @v2
```

So, you are not giving us full information:

- query
- data
- error message

Comment: yes it works its my fault : (  im just trying to  set @AccTotal = @AccTotal + (SELECT sum(AccDebit-AccCredit) FROM @VT WHERE RowNum = @Iter) 
     set @BaseTotal = @BaseTotal + (SELECT sum(BaseDebit-BaseCredit) FROM @VT WHERE RowNum = @Iter) 
     update @VT set AccTotal=@AccTotal, BaseTotal=@BaseTotal WHERE  RowNum = @Iter    but i want to set the two variables @AccTotal and @Base in same select